# "Дыра" в окне без границы

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь создать метод, который будет рисовать окно с неким уведомлением. Уведомление представляет собой форму без границы, на которой размещается Label с требуемым текстом. Уведомление должно отображаться в течении какого-то времени, не захватывая фокус.

В конце-концов, мне удалось окно нужным образом, однако в итоге вместо контрола рисуется фон за окном, т.е. окно выглядит как дырка:

[image: Уведомление]

На скриншоте красная рамка - это не рамка, а форма. На "пустом" месте должен быть контрол.

Сам проект, строго говоря, не WinForms, а библиотека классов (4.6) с референсом на `System.Wndows.Forms`.

Её код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace someNamespace
{
    public class Overlay
    {
        class Notification : Form
        {
            protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation => true;

            private const int WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008;
            protected override CreateParams CreateParams
            {
                get
                {
                    CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
                    createParams.ExStyle |= (WS_EX_TOPMOST);
                    return createParams;
                }
            }

            public Notification(string Message): base()
            {
                BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 10, 320, 240);

                var label = new Label();
                label.Text = Message;
                label.Location = new Point(10, 10);
                label.Size = new Size(300, 220);

                Controls.Add(label);

                Enabled = false;
            }

            public void Show(int Delay)
            {
                Deactivate += ShowAgain();
                Show();
                Task.Delay(Delay).Wait();
                Deactivate -= ShowAgain();
                Close();
            }

            EventHandler ShowAgain()
            {
                return (s, e) => Show();
            }
        }

        static Dictionary<string, Notification> notifications = new    Dictionary<string, Notification>();

    public void Notify(string Message, int Delay)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();

        if (!notifications.ContainsKey(Message))
            notifications.Add(Message, new Notification(Message));
        var n = notifications[Message];

        n.Show(Delay);
    }
}
```

}

Консольное приложение, которое дёргает библиотеку:

```
class Program
{
    static Overlay overlay = new Overlay();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        overlay.Notify("Привет!", 5000);
    }
}
```

Как вернуть контрол на место?

Comment: А где вызов Application.Run? Нет Application.Run - нет отрисовки, все просто!

Comment: @PavelMayorov Балииин!!1 Спасибо :)